# AWS Textract and X-ray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray, amazon-textract

Does `textract` not support `X-ray` at all? I could not find anything in the documentation, and trying some rather obvious things yielded nothing. To wit:

- I have a pipeline where a lambda invokes `StartDocumentTextDetection`.
- I am passing it an SNS topic which will get notified when the detection finishes. The topic is enabled for X-ray.
- There is an SQS queue subscribed to the topic, and another lambda which gets triggered by the SQS.
- The code is in Python, and I have patched `boto3` (`botocore`, really) as documented.

In my service map, there is a gap between the lambda that performs the invocation and the lambda that gets fired when textract finishes. It is as if tracing information gets ignored by textract. Moreover, no tracing appears for the topic, further suggesting that textract has ignored it. Tracing starts again when the downstream lambda fires.

Questions:

1. Is this the expected behavior, or have I missed something in the documentation for how to turn on x-ray tracing for textract?
2. If this is indeed correct, does anyone know of any plans to support xray from textract?

Thanks,

/ji

PS: This is not a complete show-stopper, as all the lambdas in the pipeline access a particular bucket, which appears in all the traces, and which in turn "bridges", so to speak, the gap between the lambdas on either side of textract.

Answer (score 0):

textract does not integrate with X-Ray. If the textract is wrapped by 2 AWS managed services, for example SQS -> textract -> SQS, trace is broken at texttract.